# Batch application with several process

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have to implement a solution of a standalone application to manage and execute several batch process. Is there any state of the art solution with Java and Spring. I've been reading about it and spring boot with spring batch seems to be the real thing, but I'd like to know if the proper way is to create a spring boot application for each batch process or if its better to create all the process inside the same application. Is it safe to expose rest services to invoke the executions? Is it better to execute them only through command line? I'm kinda newby in this!
Thanks in advance!
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Data Flow is what you're looking for.  It's a tool for orchestrating Spring Boot based Spring Batch jobs (among other things).  You can read more about it on the project page here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking is **`scheduling, and management`** of Different batch jobs across environments.
there are different tools  available for this like **Control – M  , autosys  etc** .

Spring had **spring-batch-admin** project for similar requirement

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/getting-started.html